# Why Strict 2 group is equivalent to Group object in Category of Categories?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

***Standard definition*** of **Strict 2-Group** says that it is a *Strict Monoidal Category* in which every morphism is *invertible*  and each object has a *strict inverse*.

Also it is a well known fact that **Strict 2-Group** is a *group object* in the *category of categories* and the *category object* in the *category of groups.*
Now in terms of the **last two equivalent formulations** of **Strict 2-Group** we must have a **group structure** on both the *Object set* and the  *Morphism* set of the **Strict 2-Group** *induced by the associated bifunctor* of the **strict monoidal category.**

But I am not able to understand how  ***Standard definition*** is actually implying that we have an *identity element* in the morphism set and  each *morphism* has an **inverse** with respect to the *binary operation* in the *morphism set* *induced by the associated bifunctor* of the Strict Monoidal category.

Also I could not get how we are getting the **associativity** of the  *binary oporation* in the the morphism set *induced by the associated bifunctor* of the **strict monoidal category.**

I felt from the ***Standard definition*** we can only say that *object set* is a group and the *morphism set* is equipped with a *binary operation* **NOTE** ( *Binary operations* on both object and morphism sets here are  *induced by the associated bifunctor* of the **strict monoidal category.**) . But existence of *inverse* , *associativity* and *identity* in the morphism set are not guaranted.

Hence if those **two equivalent formulations** are true and also the **Standard definition** is correct then I must be misunderstanding something here conceptually.

**Then where am I making the mistake?**

**NOTE:**

***Here I am NOT ASKING*** : Whether each morphism is invertible or not?

The issue of invertibility of morphism(in categorical sense) is already discussed in the paper by R. Brown and C. Spencer, G-groupoids, crossed modules and the fundamental groupoid of a topological group, Proc. Kon. Ned. Akad. v. Wet, 79, (1976), 296 – 302, [pdf]). They discussed about invertibility
of arrow in categorical sense ( **that is whether a group object in Cat( Category of Categories) has a groupoid structure or not?** ..)

**Here I am asking** about the existence of group inverse in the morphism set with respect to the binary operation induced from the “ Bifunctor of the Strict 2 - group”

The link from where I read the **standard definition** are the following:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0307200.pdf , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-group#Strict_2-groups

If my question is stupid or not up to the standard of this forum then  I am seeking apology before hand .

Thank you.

Comment: I thought the same about the MO version of your question, but could you please use *less* formatting ? Right now it's just confusing and distracting.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes it is basically the same question. I did not get answer there(MO) even after specifying the reason that my question is not duplicate to the question you stated. So I asked it here again to get some helpful answer.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I used more formatting because I do not want others to get confused with my question (like the last time you got confused and said my question is duplicate to that question). In fact invertibility of morphism was never my question.(Which I mentioned here explicitly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The associativity and existence of an identity on the set of morphism is already given by the strict monoidal structure. Indeed, the functors $(A,B,C)\mapsto (A \otimes B) \otimes C$ and $(A,B,C)\mapsto A\otimes (B\otimes C)$ are equal, hence also their morphism parts are equal; and similarly, the functor $A\mapsto I\otimes A$ is equal to the identity functor, thus also at the level of morphism, where it is defined by $f\mapsto 1_I\otimes f$, which shows that $1_I$ is an identity for the set of . Note that this part is true for any strict $2$-category.

Inverses are a little bit more tricky : here we need to use some sort of variant of the Eckmann-Hilton argument. More specifically, note first that if $A\otimes \widehat{A}=I$ then we have $1_A\otimes 1_{\widehat{A}}=1_{A\otimes \widehat{A}}=1_I$, so identity maps have inverse for $\otimes$.

Moreover for any $f:A\to B$ and $g:C\to D$, we have, by the functoriality of the tensor $\otimes$ :
$$f\otimes g=(1_B\circ f)\otimes (g\circ 1_C)=(1_B\otimes g)\circ (f\otimes 1_C).$$
In particular, if we want $\widehat{f}:\widehat{A}\to \widehat{B}$ to be the inverse of $f$ for the operation $\otimes$, we must have
$$1_B\otimes \widehat{f}=(f\otimes 1_{\widehat{A}})^{-1}=f^{-1}\otimes 1_{\widehat{A}}^{-1}=f^{-1}\otimes 1_{\widehat{A}},$$
and multiplying both sides by $1_{\widehat{B}}$ shows that we must choose $\widehat{f}=1_{\widehat{B}}\otimes f^{-1}\otimes 1_{\widehat{A}}$. Now we can check that $\widehat{f}\otimes f =1_I$ using the interchange law as above.

Comment: Thanks!  I am trying to understand your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now got my answer.